# Speedup emulator on flutter development envirnment

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I'm working with flutter project. I use andriod emulator to test it. When I'm testing emulator is getting slow and get stuck. Sometimes cannot scroll lisviews for few minutes.

I tried hardware accelaration method like Set graphics in emulated performance as Hardware - GLES 2.0.
But It didn't gives much performance.

Is there any methods to speedup my emulator for flutter development?

Comment: What are the specs of the computer you're currently running on?

Comment: @JonasZebari 8GB RAM, core i7 3.60GHz CPU